# Howto add start-up option / command-line option to Google Chrome

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, shortcuts

I'm new to Ubuntu (switched from Windows to 19.04) and I want to give it a try until December 19 and then decide if I want to keep using it or if I switch back to windows.
On Windows I was used to shortcuts, for example on desktop. You can add start-up options / command-line options to an application by right clicking the shortcut and adding `--ssl-version-min=tls1.2` behind the path of the application which is getting executed.
Now how can I do that for Ubuntu?
I already tried to find the location of Google Chrome with the command `which` however I'm not sure if it is smart to edit this file or if it is even possible to add the option `--ssl-version-min=tls1.2` in there.

Comment: Do you already have a starter for Chrome? If so you can edit this `.desktop` file and change the `Exec` line adding the command line option. If not just create one via the GUI and alter it or create a new starter yourself as explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/475085/507051). Let me know if this helps so that I can make it an answer.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was searching, you can post it as answer, I will mark it as solved then. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Big thanks to [dessert](https://askubuntu.com/users/507051) for solving my problem. I want to quickly share my "config" with you:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Google Chrome
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --ssl-version-min=tls1.2
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Icon=google-chrome
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
```

Note you can also edit `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` to make the change affective system wide (But keep in mind you have to change it for incognito and new tab in this file as well). :)

Comment: I’m glad I were able to help! There’s no need for two answers, but you could add the path you used for the `.desktop` file. Here’s an upvote, just accept your own answer as the solution (in two days).